# Stop rotation youtubevideo player ios sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, youtube

My App Support only portrait mode. I was playing you tube video with the help of embedded HTML (LoadHTML)(Like:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3F1_04GLrPs) and it is working properly, even after rotation. But now i am playing all ready embedded video (Like:  http://www.youtube.com/embed/3F1_04GLrPs) with (LoadRequist) it is playing video but after rotate the iPhone to landscape and press the done it also rotate my view controller to landscape while my app only support Portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

    // Return YES for supported orientations

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```